# Styling a variable data without undeclared variable error

Tags: php, html, validation

I have an error and that is happening because I'm changing the `$item` name cause I want it to be uppercase. I've already done it for most of my code but for some reason I'm having some trouble doing so in here.

Here is the code:

```
public function check($source, $items = array()) {
        foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
            foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

                $value = $source[$item];
                $item = escape($item);

                if ($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                    $error = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
                    $this->addError(ucfirst($error) . " is required");
                } else if(!empty($value)){
                    switch($rule) {
                        case 'min':
                            if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'max':
                            if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'matches':
                            if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                                $item = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . ' does not match ' . $rule_value);
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'unique':
                            $check = $this->_db->get('*', $rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                            if ($check->count()){
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . ' is already in use!');
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(empty($this->_errors)) {
            $this->_passed = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Problematic code is:

```
if ($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
    $item = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
    $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " is required");
}
```

I'm trying to make it so it outputs `Password again is required` instead of `password_again is required`. Everything in the `switch($rule)` statement is working properly but like I said I don't know why it doesn't work at that specific line. Anyone got an idea?

Exact Error: `Notice: Undefined index: password confirm in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Validate.php on line 13`.

What I thought of:

1. Suppression of the notice. This is good but I would really love it if this can be fixed.

Code Request [Source & Item]:

```
$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'email' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 7,
            'max' => 64,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 7,
            'max' => 32
        ),
        'password_confirm' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
        )
    ));
```

Var Dump Result:

```
string(5) "email" 
Notice: Undefined property: Validate::$addError in      C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Validate.php on line 18
NULL string(8) "password" 
Notice: Undefined property: Validate::$addError in  C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Validate.php on line 18
NULL string(16) "password confirm" 
Notice: Undefined property: Validate::$addError in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Validate.php on line 18
NULL 
Notice: Undefined index: password confirm in     C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Validate.php on line 13
```

New Working Code:

```
if ($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
    $error = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
    $this->addError(ucfirst($error) . " is required");
}
```

Comment: Post your source and items please?

Comment: Debug the if statement:

>$this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " is required");

TO:

    var_dump( $item );
    $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " is required");
    var_dump( $this->addError ); //or your error array.
    die;

Comment: @VladimirRamik I posted it in the main post. It was kinda messy down here.

Comment: @VladimirRamik Okay I tried changing the variable name to $error instead and that works but I don't know why $item doesn't work. I've posted the edited line of code in the post. If you think there is a better way please tell me. (Not even sure if this fixes it or just covers up for the notice)

Comment: @VladimirRamik I did not notice that the curly braces have not ended yet and so part of the function was cut off. Can you please look at the code again?

Comment: I posted my full edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an empty check which is why the notice gets displayed when email, password or password_confirm is missing:

```
            if( !empty( $source[$item] ) )
            {
                $value = $source[$item];
                $item = escape($item);

                if ($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                    $item = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
                    $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " is required");
                } else if(!empty($value)){
                    switch($rule) {
                        case 'min':
                            if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'max':
                            if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'matches':
                            if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                                $item = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . ' does not match ' . $rule_value);
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'unique':
                            // $check = $this->_db->get('*', $rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));

                            if ( 1 == 1 ){
                                $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . ' is already in use!');
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->addError( $item . ' cannot be empty!' );
                break;
            }
```

I would recommend a simpler solution.

Full replication as requested:

```
    function escape( $sValue )
    {
        return trim( $sValue );
    }
class test
{
    public $aErrors = array();
    public function addError( $sError )
    {
        $this->aErrors[] = $sError;
    }

    public function check($source, $items = array()) {
            foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
                foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

                    if( !empty( $source[$item] ) )
                    {
                        $value = $source[$item];
                        $item = escape($item);

                        if ($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                            $item = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
                            $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " is required");
                        } else if(!empty($value)){
                            switch($rule) {
                                case 'min':
                                    if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                                        $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                                    }
                                break;
                                case 'max':
                                    if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                                        $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . " must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                                    }
                                break;
                                case 'matches':
                                    if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                                        $item = str_replace(array('_'), ' ', $item);
                                        $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . ' does not match ' . $rule_value);
                                    }
                                break;
                                case 'unique':
                                    // $check = $this->_db->get('*', $rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));

                                    if ( 1 == 1 ){
                                        $this->addError(ucfirst($item) . ' is already in use!');
                                    }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->addError( $item . ' cannot be empty!' );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
}
}
$_POST[ 'email' ] = '';
$_POST[ 'password' ] = '';
$_POST[ 'password_confirm' ] = '';
$aValidation = $cTest->check( $_POST, 
    array( 'email' => array( 'required' => true, 'min' => 7, 'max' => 64, 'unique' => 'users' ), 
    'password' => array( 'required' => true, 'min' => 7, 'max' => 32 ), 
    'password_confirm' => array( 'required' => true, 'matches' => 'password' ) ));
var_dump( $cTest->aErrors );
var_dump( $aValidation );
```

Comment: Can you look at my code again? Sorry about that should have looked where the function ended...

Comment: When I replicated it you were missing an ending }